# Microsoft Excel Find and Replace with regular expression

Tags: excel

Hello I have a data sheet in excel divided by 4 columns: sku (product's number), product name, category (product's category) and price.

one of the product category is t-shirt. I want to reduce all the t-shirt price by $50. For example: a red t-shirt is now priced at $200 after the reduction it will be $150, a white t-shirt is now priced at $300, after the reduction it will be $250 and so on

is there any regular expression command for excel to do that in one go...so I don't have to replace them one by one.

And also I want to change all the pants (category) price to $38.
So the command has to scan the category column, find the word pants and find its price and replace it with $38.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this quickly with two steps:

1. Make a 5th column with the formula (assuming data starts in Column A and second row): `=if(C2="t-shirt", D2-50, if(c2="pants", 38.00, D2))` and copy that down all the rows
2. Copy and paste-special->values into your price column.

Comment: I tried that the first step it work, thanks, but the no. 2 step, I get stuck. Do I need to highlight the price column first? (D2-D100) and then go to paste option->paste special, and then paste the formula?

Comment: I think I get it, just copy the whole value of the the new column to the price column, correct?